# HM-10 BLE master and send data to specific characteristic

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, at-command, hm-10

I have small question about HM-10 ble module and master role.

I tried 2 scenarios.

Android app as master and hm-10 as slave:

From android app I can connect to hm-10 and its characteristic .

Everything works OK.

I have problem with second scenario: HM-10 as master and my ble device (LEGO SBRICK) as slave.

What I've done:

- AT+ROLE1 - Set up to Central
- Mode AT+IMME1 - Start from RESET
- AT+SHOW1 - Show discovered devices
- AT+DISC? - Discover Devices
- AT+CON connect

Now my question is:

SBRICK is listening for ble command on service X and characteristic Y.

How can I send data from my HM-10 to specific characteristic of my SBRICK device ?

I can not find AT command for that.

I hope I didn't miss something from ble specification.

Any help please...

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there isn't an AT command to set a specific characteristic value.

The HM10 is a serial-port emulation device - It has a BLE characteristic, which displays all serial data (except AT commands). You will likely be able to find the service and characteristics details in the documentation (although I had a quick look and couldn't see anything).

So, data written to the serial port should appear as the value of that characteristic. Data written to that characteristic should be delivered out of the TX serial port pin on the HM10 module.

If you want to interrogate the device to find out it's serial and characteristic values, try using a debugging app - I use `Light Blue` on iOS, which will show all services and characteristics present on a device and show their properties and details.

Comment: Confused...does this mean I dont need to do anything extra to send data from hm10 to say, hm12, other than the typical: ROLE1 & AT+CON?

Answer (score 0):

[pfodApp](http://www.forward.com.au/pfod/index.html) now supports BLE devices including HM-10.  The free pfodDesigner lets you create custom custom Android menus and then generate the Arduino code for your particular hardware.

pfodApp supports data logging and plotting also.